# PHP MySQL: Display all column names from a given table and the values for any single given row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to parse all the column fields and data of a single row of any selected mysql table.

The reason behind this is to make a 'universal'-like Table parser of any given single row.

For example I have this table '**tbl1**':

```
+----+---------------------+---------+---------+--+
| id | date                | amounta | amountb |  |
+----+---------------------+---------+---------+--+
| 1  | 2014-02-28 05:58:41 | 148     | 220     |  |
+----+---------------------+---------+---------+--+
| 2  | 2014-01-20 05:58:41 | 50      | 285     |  |
+----+---------------------+---------+---------+--+
| 3  | 2014-03-30 05:58:41 | 501     | 582     |  |
+----+---------------------+---------+---------+--+
```

and **I want to be able to select table *tbl1* and *id = 1* to export into:**

```
<label>id <input type="text" value="1"/></label>
<label>date <input type="text" value="2014-02-28 05:58:41"/></label>
<label>amounta <input type="text" value="148"/></label>
<label>amountb <input type="text" value="220"/></label>
```

This is what I have thus far:

```
if ($_GET['p'] && $_GET['table']) {
    include ("con.php");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `" . $_GET['table'] . "` WHERE id = '" . $_GET['p'] . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $fields[] = $row['0'];
        $p = $row;
    }

    $fields = array();
    $res = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `" . $_GET['table'] . "`");
    while ($x = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $fields[] = $x['Field'];
    }

    foreach($fields as $f) {
        foreach($p as $obj) {
            echo '<label>' . $f . ' <input type="text" value="' . $p[$f] . '"></label>';
        };
    }

    mysql_close();
}
```

The problem I'm sure is somewhere between the foreach looping. I know its totally wrong but im not quite sure how to solve this problem.

Basically the idea is to select all column names from **$_GET['table']** and for each column name find its value where id = **$_GET['p']**;

Comment: Are you getting data from query? What is print_r(fields); ?

Comment: Be careful. Your code is vulnerable for mysql injection. Make sure to escape input and use libraries that are not deprecated. Like mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: @Tobias its locally. There is no internet connection going on. Thank you

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan I am getting data from both such as $fields and $p.

Comment: have you declared `$p` as an array ? `$p = $row` would give you the last result in the result set , if there are more than one results

Comment: @anurupr As stated in the question, I do not want more than one results or rows. Just 1 row / 1 id.

Comment: @jQuerybeast: But it is better to learn it the correct way. It's your decision. :)

Comment: @jQuerybeast, you're right. my bad. then i don't think you need the second foreach loop, since you're looping through the `$fields` array anyway and you have only a single-level array `$p`. so looping through `$fields` array and displaying each field value using `$p[$f]` should do the trick

Comment: @anurupr Can you post an answer of which could possible work? I've tried alot with no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `$p` is a single-level array like

```
    Array (
            'field1' => 'value1',
            'field2' => 'value2',
            ...
          )
```

and `$fields` is an array like this

```
    Array (
            0 => 'field1',
            1 => 'field2',
            ...
          )
```

Then this should work

```
foreach($fields as $f) {
       echo '<label>' . $f . ' <input type="text" value="' . $p[$f] . '"></label>';    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mysql_fetch_field`](http://php.net/mysql-fetch-field).

```
$fields = array();
while($f = mysql_fetch_field($query)) $fields[] = $f->name;
```

In this way you can get all field names, works for any kind of query rather than just `SELECT *`

Comment: I understand this could possible be the answer but I have no idea where and what should I replace. Do i need to do foreach? I am on the very early stage of PHP. Thank you

Comment: I literally gave you how to create your `$fields` array. Take the code you wrote to get `$fields` and replace it with this. Amazingly, it'll work!